Unity Hololens 2 gameobjects not appearing
I followed the following tutorial step-by-step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/learn-mrtk-tutorials/1-7-exercise-hand-interaction-with-objectmanipulator
Basically I added two cubes to the scene and added hand interaction. When I start the play mode in unity, I can see everything the way expected. However, when I deploy the app to my hololens 2, the two cubes are not appearing. There is also no unity splash screen showing up. The only thing I see is first the loading animation (4 spinning spheres) and then the following screen:

I use: Unity 2021.3.43f1
These are my MRTK3 package versions:
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.accessibility: 1.0.3-pre.20
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.audio: 3.0.3
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.core: 4.0.0-pre.1
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.diagnostics: 3.0.2
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.extendedassets: 3.0.2
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.input: 4.0.0-pre.1
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.spatialmanipulation: 4.0.0-pre.1
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.standardassets: 3.2.0
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.tools: 3.0.3
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.uxcomponents: 4.0.0-pre.1
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.uxcomponents.noncanvas: 4.0.0-pre.1
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.uxcore: 4.0.0-pre.1
org.mixedrealitytoolkit.windowsspeech: 3.0.3
Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin: 1.8.1

Could you double-check the XR plugin settings? Please open the Project Settings panel, navigate to the XR Plug-in Management page, and select the Universal Windows Platform tab. Ensure that “Initialize XR on Startup” is selected.


I double-checked and “Initialize XR on Startup" was already selected correctly

Hi Luca, could I know which version of VS you use to deploy your app?

Hi, I am using Visual Studio Community 2019

Hi Luca, please use VS 2022 and try deploying again. VS 2022 is the recommended version for MR development. For more details on installing VS 2022 and its workloads for MR development, please see - Install the tools - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn.
